# How do I make Python pick the correct module without manually modifying sys.path?

Tags: python, import, path, module

I have made some changes in a python module in my checked out copy of a repository, and need to test them. However, when I try to run a script that uses the module, it keeps importing the module from the trunk of the repository, which is of no use to me.

I tried setting PYTHONPATH, which did nothing at all. After some searching around, I found that anything in the .pth files under site-packages directory will be put in even before PYTHONPATH (which to me defeats the purpose of having it). I believe this is the cause for my module not being picked.

Am I correct? If so, what is the way to override this (without modifying the script to have a `sys.path.insert(0,path)` )?

Edit: In reply to NicDumz - the original repository was under `/projects/spam`. The python modules were part of this in `/projects/spam/sources/python/a/b/`. However, these are 'built' every night using a homegrown make variant which then puts them into `/projects/spam/build/lib/python/a/b/`. The script is using the module under this last path only.
 I have checked out the entire repository to under `/home/sundar/spam`, and made changes in `/home/sundar/spam/sources/python/a/b/mymodule.py`. I've set my PYTHONPATH to `/home/sundar/spam/sources/python` and tried to `import a.b.mymodule` with no success.

Comment: I think that wit would be easier with a longer description of your environment. Where is the trunk module installed? How was it installed? And then, for your copy, did you only copy a small submodule, or the whole tree? where was it placed? etc...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to install [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and use it to set up different environments for different purposes. In one environment, you would import modules from the trunk of the repository, but in another environment you would have a mixture of trunk modules and test modules.

By keeping everything separate like this you make it easier to rollback changes (just delete the whole virtual environment folder) and you greatly reduce the risk that your test rigging will end up being committed to the repository.

Comment: But this would create the problem of keeping the two environments in sync isn't it? Also, I see that I can make virtual-env not see the global site-packages, but this is not what I want - what I need is to have my modules override the global ones whenever there is a conflict, and otherwise pick them. Is this possible?

Comment: You do not want to keep the two environments in sync. You want one environment to run the repository code as it was checked out. The other environment will have some changed modules that you are working on right now. When you have finished your work, you delete the secong environment. To start working on a different set of modules, copy the repository environment, and start changing things.

In your work environment, you can install any packages and modules that you want, and edit them as well, and they will override anything in the repository.

Comment: At any time, you can leave your development virtualenvironment to run the unchanged repository code, then go back into the development virtualenvironment to test your own code changes. When your changes are completed, you simply copy them to the checked out repository, run unit tests one more time, and commit them.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a small script, such as the one below, that prefixes sys.path, then set PYTHONSTARTUP to use that script.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:/temp')
```

For example...

```
C:\temp>set PYTHONSTARTUP=c:\temp\tst.py
C:\temp>C:\Python26\python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['c:/temp', '', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\pyyaml-3.08-py2.6-win32.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\
lib\\site-packages\\pyglet-1.1.3-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\
simpy-2.0.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-0.11.1-py2.6.egg
', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial-unknown-py2.6-win32.egg', 'c:\\t
emp', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26
\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python2
6', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32
', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-pack
ages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, PYTHONSTARTUP is apparently not picked up when Python interpreter is run non-interactively. Is there a way to run a script (along with its commandline arguments) from within the interactive interpreter? If so, this solution would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your current working directory is first in the `sys.path`.  Anything there trumps anything else on the path.

Copy the "test version" to some place closer to the front of the list of directories in `sys.path`, like your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setup script with [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), then do a `python setup.py develop`. It will add a link to your working copy in a .pth file, overriding any installed version.

When you are done, you can simply delete the link in the .pth file.